# tips on reducing the number of parameters passed into a function

Tags: actionscript-3, coding-style

HI,

I'm working on a AS3 project, originally written by someone else. I'm re-writing one of the functions in a class. This function creates a simple value object, but the function takes in 16 parameters which is a mess.

What is a good way to re-write this so it looks neater and is more read about?

Thanks

Stephen

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what is essential to that piece of code. Perhaps write a wrapper function that takes in fewer arguments but calls that one?

Comment: can you post the list of parameters and a description of what the function does?  with so many parameters there's a good chance that it's trying to handle too much and should be redesigned.

Comment: Maybe the function is doing too much. Try to split it into several smaller functions. I'm confident that this will decrease the number of parameters per function, too.

Answer (score 1):

Or perhaps, if there's an obvious relationship between the parameters, create a class. Instantiate the class, fill in the values, then pass the object.

Instead of

```
myfunc(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, ..., p16);
```

you get

```
c1 = new c1();
c1.p1 = val
c1.p2 = val
...
c1.p16 = val
```

then you call

```
myfunc(c1);
```

Comment: Yep. Sometimes these types of objects are called "Value Objects" and are meant to be used to transfer data from function to function or from class to class.

Comment: Well I am trying to create a series of Value objects (all the same type) and then add them to a ArrayCollection. So I created a function that returns the value object, this function takes in the 16 parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for the following:

1. Check if some parameters can be spared (not used, duplicates, can be retrieved other way), with 16 parameters I wouldn't be surprised if some of them are redundant.
2. Check if some of the parameters are logically connected to each other. It may worth to create an object containing them all. In case the same set of parameters travels to other functions as well, then you have a winner.
3. Check the design of the class, it could be that some of them should be class members.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go either for Chaining http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining, passing anonymous object with variables set, like:

```
someFunction({id:1, pizzas:"1", types:["triple cheese"], location:"sun"});
```

Or, like someone mentioned, Value Objects http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object, depending on how you like your code :).